# Internal storage fills up

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I had a Sony Xperia C with a 16GB memory card. My internal storage kept filling up which made it unable to update or download any apps. The only apps I had were WhatsApp and Instagram. Sent my phone in. Had to pay for repairs, was in for 6 weeks, and got the phone back but still the same errors.

I got a new phone Huawei G6, a brand new 16GB, and a new Google Play Store account. The phone is set for the default storage location to SD card. Moved all app that I could to an SD card. I only have 10 songs and about 100 pictures. I clear cache every day, probably 500 every day. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Please help.

Comment: What is the free memory left in your phone out of usable 16gb? and Have a look at the Storage view in your settings..Settings-> Storage would give you how much memory each media is using and shown separtely as applications, video, songs, photos etc..you can analyse which area is occupying most memory

Comment: Sounds like the `insufficient-memory` tag is a hit here (just added it). Please follow up to [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for first-aid and useful links. Then return here and either [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) (when solved), or [edit] it and point out what you've tried and where you're still stuck. Good luck!

Comment: Related: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your internal app partition is full. Check it on Settings> Storage> under phone storage what left as available on app section. If it is full (150mb free is not usable) you have 2 options:

1. You can swap your external SD. You can read full note here: (NB: it works if you have a MTK device, I don't know what if other devices) [How to swap phone storage with SD card](http://www.skyneel.com/2014/06/how-to-swap-phone-storage-with-sd-card-in-Android-device.html?m=1)
2. Partition of external SD. read it here: [How to Partition SD Card and Use Link2SD in any Android Phone with Screenshots](https://awanstuff.wordpress.com/2013/01/20/how-to-partition-sd-card-and-use-link2sd-in-any-android-phone-with-screenshots/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the T-Moble store yesterday and asked them about this. They said that with updates and only 8 gigs of memory, my phone will fill up. I will just have to buy a new phone with bigger internal memory because some programs can't be shifted to the SD card. A 16 gig internal memory is good. I wish they would have told me this when I bought the phone.